# Equivalence of two Ito formulae

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two $1$-dimensional Ito processes. There are two Ito formulae for the product $X_tY_t$ given by

1. $d\left(X_tY_t\right)=X_tdY_t+Y_tdX_t+d\left[X_t,Y_t\right]$
2. $d\left(X_tY_t\right)=X_tdY_t+Y_tdX_t+dX_tdY_t$.

$dX_tdY_t$ is to be calculated using the rules $dt\cdot dt=0$, $dt\cdot dW_t=0$, $dW_t\cdot dW_t=dt$. Clearly for the above to be consistent we need $dX_tdY_t=d\left[X_t,Y_t\right]$ but I am unable to see why this holds. Would anyone be able to shed some light on this?

Edit: Fixed formulae.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the product formulae which you wrote are incorrect, it should have been 
$$ d(X_tY_t) = X_t \mathrm{d}Y_t + Y_t\mathrm{d}X_t + \mathrm{d}X_t\mathrm{d}Y_t.$$
However, there is a lot of notation involved in the above. Let me start without the abuse of notation, for two Ito processes $X$ and $Y$ we have that
$$( \star) \ \qquad  X_tY_t = X_0Y_0 + \int_0^t X_s \mathrm{d}Y_s + \int_0^t Y_s \mathrm{d}X_s +[X,Y]_t,$$
where $[X, Y]$ stands for a covariation of two processes ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation)).

We can re-writte the equation $( \star) $ as follows
$$\int_0^t \mathrm{d}(X_sY_s) = \int_0^t X_s \mathrm{d}Y_s + \int_0^t Y_s \mathrm{d}X_s +\int_0^t \mathrm{d}[X,Y]_s.$$
Now we make use of the following abuse of notation
$$ \mathrm{d}(XY) = X\mathrm{d}Y + Y\mathrm{d}X + \mathrm{d}X\mathrm{d}Y,$$
where $\mathrm{d}X\mathrm{d}Y$ denotes $\mathrm{d}[X,Y]$. This notation is a brilliant one because it make our calculations quicker and it still easy to come back to the formal ones. In particular, it is widely used in quantitative finance. Here are some notes where you can find properties of the quadratic variation for Ito processes (without proofs) [link](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/irene.klein/fvm_1.pdf).

Comment: If $dX_tdY_t$ is just notation for $d\left[X_t,Y_t\right]$ why should we be allowed to treat it as a product of two differentials and apply the multiplication rules? I would have thought that the left hand side could only be evaluated by calculating the right hand side if it were pure notation. I guess that's the part I am confused about.

Comment: This notation was not chosen by guess or to look nice. It was chosen to be such because $\mathrm{d}[X, Y]_t$ has such nice properties to allow us to think about it as $\mathrm{d}X_t\mathrm{d}Y_t$ and apply multiplication rules etc. You just need to study the properties of quadratic variation and covariation, this is why I gave you the link to start with.

Comment: I tried looking for a proof of this result before asking this question but did not manage to find one. Would you happen to know of any resources regarding this property of $d\left[X_t,Y_t\right]$ and $dX_tdY_t$?

Comment: First look at http://russell-davidson.arts.mcgill.ca/e761/Ito.pdf (Theorem 3.44, Remark 14.2 (Differential Representation) and Theorem 10.48 ) you may also want to read https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/01/18/quadratic-variations-and-integration-by-parts/ and https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/properties-of-quadratic-variations/